# MLE regression that accounts for two constraints

Tags: r, logistic-regression

So I am wanting to create a logistic regression that simultaneously satisfies two constraints.

The link here, outlines how to use the Excel solver to maximize the value of Log-Likelihood value of a logistic regression, **but I am wanting to implement a similar function in R**

What I am trying to create in the end is an [injury risk function](http://www-esv.nhtsa.dot.gov/Proceedings/22/files/22ESV-000089.pdf). These take an [S-shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function.

As we see, the risk curves are calculated from the following equation

[image]

Lets take some dummy data to begin with

```
set.seed(112233)
A <- rbinom(153, 1, 0.6)
B <- rnorm(153, mean = 50, sd = 5)
C <- rnorm(153, mean = 100, sd = 15)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

Lets assume `A` indicates if a bone was broken, `B` is the bone density and `C` is the force applied.

So we can form a logistic regression model that uses `B` and `C` are capable of explaining the outcome variable `A`. A simple example of the regression may be:

[image]

Or

```
glm(A ~ B + C, data=df1, family=binomial())
```

Now we want to make the **first assumption** that at zero force, we should have zero risk. This is further explained as A1. on pg.124 [here](https://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/Proceedings/y2002/files/JSM2002-001117.pdf)

Here we set our `A1=0.05` and solve the equation

```
A1 = 1 - (1-P(0))^n
```

where `P(0)` is the probability of injury when the injury related parameter is zero and `n` is the sample size.
We have our sample size and can solve for `P(0)`. We get `3.4E-4`. Such that:

[image]

The **second assumption** is that we should maximize the log-likelihood function of the regression

We want to maximize the following equation

[image]

Where *pi* is estimated from the above equation and *yi* is the observed value for non-break for each interval

My what i understand, I have to use one of the two functions in R to define a function for max'ing LL. I can use `mle` from base R or the `mle2` from `bbmle` package.

I guess I need to write a function along these lines

```
log.likelihood.sum <- function(sequence, p) {
log.likelihood <- sum(log(p)*(sequence==1)) + sum(log(1-p)*(sequence==0))
}
```

But I am not sure where I should account for the first assumption. Ie. am I best to build it into the above code, and if so, how? Or will it be more effiecient to write a secondary finction to combine the two assumptions. Any advice would be great, as I have very limited experience in writing *and understanding* functions

Comment: There is no assumption in that binomial model that at zero force the risk of fracture would be zero. You might argue that there should be such an assumption, but that would require a different analysis.And this appears to be much more about how to set up models than it is about coding, so voting to migrate.

Comment: The paper you cite has this observation: "An unsuitable statistical model can lead to a bias in the risk prediction. An injury risk curve calcu- lated with the logistic regression does not pass through zero and will always predict a non-zero risk at zero load.".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BondedDust. You mention it requires another analysis, can you suggust how to tackle the problem. And how can one automatically migrate the problem to CV?